# Rails server (command) not persisting once SSH connection is closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm using a **Windows Azure VM** with Ubuntu to host my website in Rails.

Here's my **problem**: I open an SSH connection through PuTTY to start the server through the command

```
me@example: ~/Sites/mysite$ rails server
```

I can then view my website and everything is fine. However, when I close the SSH connection the server stops and my website goes down. How can I tell the VM (I suppose without an SSH connection?) that I want this command run persistently?

Thanks for reading,
-Adam

*tl;dr* - After closing the SSH connection to my Azure VM the rails server command stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start your rails server as a daemon otherwise it's attached to your session and will be ended as soon as you close the session. You could do this with the "-d" option.

```
$ rails server -d
```

However, it's probably better to setup an [upstart service](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Ah wow I can't believe I made such a newbie oversight. Thanks a bunch dude.